# Manually adding items to futurebuilder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-futurebuilder

I am making a shopping app. I have an api which sends 11 tabs with many products in each tab. In my code, i am using futurebuilder to show that data. I want to add a tab 'All' which shows all the products in all tabs under a single tab. But when i manually add the 12th tab, the futurebuilder throws range  error.

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..10: 11

I am guessing its because futurebuilder automatically takes number of tabs based on the number of items in snapshot. I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921611/how-to-use-nested-or-several-future-builder-in-flutter) for the body of the 'all' tab. I am wondering if it is possible to manually add tab and products in futurebuilder? If yes, how do i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For somebody else who might want to know this, you can just remove the future builder and return something like listview builder or whatever you need. Here is a very helpful [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbCmTDmt1Jo).